# Yodlee: Unable to convert image codes into captcha in getMFAResponseForSite(Captcha type) - C#

Tags: captcha, yodlee

After adding MFA enabled (captcha type MFA) site accounts through "addSiteAccounts1" API, i have got the response of image codes, which we want to convert into captcha image. I have checked with many scripts to convert but no result. Is there any simple steps to get the image(in C#).
Following is the MFA response,

```
{
   "isMessageAvailable":true,
   "fieldInfo":{
      "responseFieldType":"text",
      "imageFieldType":"image",
      "image":[
         66,
         77,
         58,
         116,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         54,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         40,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         -91,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         45,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         1,
         0,
         32,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         4,
         116,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -5,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -9,
         -9,
         -9,
         0,
         -1,
         -5,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -5,
         -1,
         0,
         -17,
         -17,
         -17,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -9,
         -13,
         -9,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -9,
         -9,
         -9,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -17,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0,
         -1,
         -1,
         -1,
         0
      ],
      "minimumLength":-1,
      "maximumLength":-1,
      "displayString":"Please enter the text shown in the image"
   },
   "timeOutTime":99900,
   "itemId":10014925,
   "retry":false
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Here you are getting image in byte array which is present as String Array in response.
You need to convert this byte array into image. There is few lines of code which will help you.

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Additionally, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv) is the link which will help you.